# What should I use to replace SDL_Flip?

Tags: graphics, sdl, d

I have a graphics engine in development, and I can't test it because there's no example on how to display an SDL_Surface on a window in SDL2, and there's no older SDL libraries to D.
I can use examples from C++ too, but even with a lot of searching on he internet I only could find tutorials for SDL 1.2.

Answer (score 8):

[`SDL_RenderPresent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent) replaced `SDL_Flip` in SDL 2.

See the [SDL 1.2 to 2.0 Migration Guide](https://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide) for more information.